# Does Mongoose enqueue queries?

Tags: database, node.js, mongoose

We're seeing some strange, though somewhat predictable behavior using Mongoose in a load test. After the test is finished, the service keeps making queries for a while after the load ends. I think it could be that the queries are being enqueued and not dropped after the timeout expires.

Lets say that we're making queries every 5ms that take 10ms to execute. With a single connection, two things could happen:

1. Half of the queries are dropped because the connection is in use.
2. The excess queries are enqueued and executed when the connection frees up.

I could not find anything in the documentation that described the behavior of Mongoose when a database is overloaded like this. It looks like the latter option is occurring.

There is an option for setting a query timeout, but it doesn't say whether that timeout is measured from the initial query request, or the execution of the query against the database. I suspect it is also the latter.

Comment: I believe this is due to Node's behavior, not Mongoose. When your request asks Mongoose for a query, that query is executed asynchronously, meaning that it will be executed "when possible". If the connection pool to the database is exhausted, the "when possible" part will be when a new connection is available in the pool, which might be long after your test ended.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose will buffer when the connection drops by default. See the [bufferCommands](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#bufferCommands) option. Otherwise, it shouldn't do any buffering based on number of requests. As Nepoxx said, that may just be due to how Node enables those requests to wait for IO.